# My.Settings.save issue in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

i hvave created a string in my `Settings` area called `DBUsername` , it is a string , there is no value.

in my code I have

```
    Dim Setting As New My.MySettings
Private Sub saveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles saveButton.Click

    If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
        name = TextBox1.Text
        Setting.DBUsername = name '(ERROR IN THIS LINE : the property DBUsername  is Read Only )`
        Setting.Save()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In the Project Settings editor (in Visual Studio) is the "Scope" of your DBUsername property set to "User" or "Application"?

Comment: why dim up a new instance of My.Setting?

Comment: @tgolisch it is set to Application .

Comment: @DanAndrews the tutorials i have watched so far have shown me that and they had no issues using that method

Comment: `Setting.DBUsername = name` seems silly but somehow it works for other persons .
it seems as if  name is being assigned to DBUsername but I should not even attempt to do so because DBUsername is read only , so i understand the error now but now i'm a little more confuse as to how others get it to work using the same method .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Project Settings editor (in Visual Studio) the "Scope" of your DBUsername property needs to be set to "User". "Application" scoped properties are read-only.

Comment: oh x_x.  i could have sworn i tried that before but it didnt work ...and now it works.
well thank you